# Problem with missing values and decision rule classification in Weka

Tags: classification, missing-data, weka

Validated community,

I have a large dataset of three classes and 22 variables from which I would like to create a decision rule/decision tree-based classification in Weka 3.8.6. The dataset is a retrospective medical study containing numerical data (such as height) and categorical data (patient tests positive/negative). The problem is that 7/22 variables have more than 50% of missing data, and these variables with the missing data contain tests that would be most useful in distinguishing between the three classes. However, the tests are costly, which is why most of the data is missing (and some of the variables are categorical).

I have tried using Ripper, J48 Consolidated, and JCHAIDStar. JCHAIDSTar has the most promising results, but the classifier makes decision nodes from missing data in the form of =? decision nodes.

I have tried removing missing data according to https://aicorespot.io/how-to-manage-missing-values-in-machine-learning-data-with-weka/ but that doesn't seem to work on categorical data.

Is there anything I can do to exclude such missing values from analysis?